# Putnam 2006 - Exercise B.6 - Alternative solution verification and questions about generalizations

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, contest-math

**CONTEXT**

Here is the orginal problem statement.

> Let $k$ be an integer greater than 1. Suppose $a_0 > 0$, and define
> $$
> a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{1}{\sqrt[k]{a_n}}
> $$
> for $n > 0$. Evaluate
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n^{k+1}}{n^k}.
> $$**

---

**PROPOSED SOLUTION**

1. Note that for $n>0$
   $$a_n \geq a_0 + \frac1{\sqrt[k]{a_0}}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt[k]{j}},$$
   and hence $(a_n)$ diverges.

**EDIT. As pointed out in comment, this step is not correct**. I am working on an alternative approach.

**EDIT 2. A nice approach is proposed in the comment by [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews)**

2. Define $b_n = a_n^{\frac{k+1}k}$. (Observe that $(b_n)$, too, is divergent.) Now, we have \begin{eqnarray}\lim_{n\to \infty}(b_{n+1}-b_n)&= &\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(a_n+a_n^{-\frac1{k}}\right)^{\frac{k+1}k}-a_n^{\frac{k+1}k}=\\&=&\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(1+a_n^{-\frac{k+1}k}\right)^{\frac{k+1}k}-1}{a_n^{-\frac{k+1}k}}=\frac{k+1}{k},\end{eqnarray}where the fundamental limit$$\frac{(1+\alpha)^m-1}{\alpha}\to m, \ \ \ \mbox{for} \ \ \alpha\to 0$$has been used.
3. By Stolz-Cesàro Theorem, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{n} = \frac{k+1}k,$$
   and hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n^{k+1}}{n^k} = \left(\frac{k+1}k\right)^k.$$
   $\blacksquare$

---

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is my solution correct?
2. Is it correct to state that the solution is valid also for any **real number $k\geq 1$**?
3. Can we further generalize? For example: what can be stated for $0<k<1$, maybe with some restriction on $a_0$?

Comment: (1) is not obvious to me. What am I missing?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks! I think I erroneously assumed $a_0>1$. I will edit the question to point out my mistake and try to find another approach!

Comment: $a_n$ is increasing, so if $a_n$ is convergent to some $a>0,$ then $a_{n+1}-a_n\to 0.$ But $a_{n+1}-a_n=1/a_{n}^{1/k}\to 1/a^{1/k}.$ Contradiction. So $a_n$ must diverge.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks! I was thinking, alternatively, to use the fact that if $a_0<1$, then $a_1>1$, so that we can still lower bound with the generalized harmonic series. But your approach is faster.

Comment: The rest of your answer looks fine.

Comment: It’s not clear where you think there might be a problem when $k\in(0,1).$ It doesn’t work when $k\in(-1,0),$ since $b_n$ is not divergent, but it might even work when $k<-1.$ Not sure.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was confused by the phrasing of the original question (in which $k$ is integer and greater than $1$), and got stuck in the generalization of my (erroneous)  step 1.

Comment: The question probably only included integer $k>1$ because it was designed for people who don’t know Cesaro-Stolz , and there is an alternate approach without it, using some integer exponent method. Or they may have wanted to leave it open for generalization by the answerer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step (1) was a bit hand-wavy. The rest of the argument looks fine.

**A replacement for step 1**

Since $a_n$ is increasing, it must converge or be divergent to $+\infty.$

If $a_n$ converges to $a>0,$ then $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)$$ converges to $a-a_0,$ and thus $1/a_n^{1/k}=a_{n+1}-a_n\to 0.$ But $1/a_n^{1/k}\to\frac1{a^{1/k}}\neq 0,$ which is a contradiction.

So $a_n$ diverges to $+\infty.$

---

This works for any sequence $$c_0>0, c_{n+1}=f(c_n)$$ where $f:\mathbb R^{+}\to\mathbb R^+$ is continuous, with $f(x)>x$ for all $x,$ by the same reasoning. We can always conclude that $c_n$ is divergent to $+\infty.$ Essentially, a limit would have to be a fixed point of $f,$ and since $c_n$ is increasing, divergence means divergence to $+\infty.$

---

It seems like it will work for all real $k>0$ and $k<-1.$ It won’t work when $k\in(-1,0)$ because $\frac{k+1}{k}<0,$ so $b_n$ doesn’t diverge then.

---

**Generalization of part (2).**

Let $g(x)$ be a positive increasing differentiable function  with $g(x)\to\infty$ $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{xg’(x)}{g(x)}=L.$$

If $$a_0>0,a_{n+1}=a_{n}\left(1+1/g(a_n)\right)$$ and $b_{n}=g(a_n).$ then I believe we can show: $$b_{n+1}-b_{n}\to L.$$

Specifically, $$g(a_{n+1})-g(a_n)=g(a_{n}+a_{n}/g(a_n))-g(a_n)=\frac{g’(z_n)a_n}{g(a_n)}$$ for some $z_n\in (a_n,a_{n+1}).$ So you need some tighter bound here on the rate of change on $f’$ to get the limit $L.$

If so, $\frac {b_{n}}n\to L,$ and hence $$\frac{g(a_n)}{n}\to L.$$

When $g(x)=x^{\alpha},\alpha>0,$ then $$\frac{xg’(x)}{g(x)}\to \alpha.$$ If $1-\alpha=-1/k,$ then $\alpha=\frac{k+1}{k}.$

Not sure about the conditions on $g.$ You might need something additional. Like $g’$ monotonic and $$\frac{g’(x)}{g’(x+x/g(x))}\to 1.$$ That might be expressed as some condition on $g’’,$ perhaps $$\frac{g’’(x)x}{g(x)g’(x)}\to 0.$$

---

If $h:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ is differentiable and $h(x)\to0$ as $x\to0^+,$ then we can define $$a_{n+1}=a_n(1+h(1/a_n))$$ then $g(x)=1/h(1/x)$ and $g’(x)=\frac{h’(1/x)}{x^2 h^2(1/x)}$ so the equivalent condition on $h$ is, with $y=1/x,$ the same $$\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{yh’(y)}{h(y)}= L.\tag1$$

If $c_n=1/a_n,$ then $c_{n+1}=\frac{c_n}{1+h(c_n)}.$ And $b_n=g(a_n)=1/h(c_n)$ so $$b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac{h(c_n)-h(c_{n+1})}{h(c_n)h(c_{n+1})}$$

Then $$h(c_n)-h(c_{n+1})=(c_n-c_{n+1})h’(z_n)=\frac{c_n h(c_n)h’(z_n)}{1+h(c_n)}$$ for some $z_n\in(c_{n+1},c_n).$ So $$b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac{c_nh’(z_n)}{h(c_{n+1})(1+h(c_n))}=\frac{c_{n+1}h’(z_n)}{h(c_{n+1}}$$ So the limit is equal to $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c_{n+1}h’(z_n)}{h(c_{n+1})}$$

If $h’$ is monotonic, then $b_{n+1}-b_n$ is between $\frac{c_{n+1}h’(c_{n+1})}{h(c_{n+1})}$ and $\frac{c_{n+1}h’(c_n)}{h(c_{n+1})}.$ The first converges to $L.$

We still need $$\frac{h’(y)}{h’\left(\frac{y}{1+h(y)}\right)}\to 1\tag1$$ to be sure $b_{n+1}-b_n$ converges to $L.$

(1) will converge if $h’(y)$ converges to a non-zero value as $y\to0^+.$

Since $u(y)=\frac{y}{1+h(y)}$ has $$u’(y)=\frac{1}{1+h(y)}-\frac{yh’(y)}{(1+h(y))^2}$$ then since $h(y)\to0$ and $yh’(y)=h(y)\frac{yh’(y)}{h(y)}\to0,$ then $u’(y)\to 1.$ So by L’Hopital:

$$\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{h’(y)}{h’(u(y))}=\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{h(y)}{h(u(y))}$$

When $h(y)\sim Cy^{\alpha},$ for some $\alpha>0,$ then the limit is the same as the limit of $$(1+h(y))^{\alpha}\to1.$$

If $h(y)=y^{\alpha}P(y)$ where  $\frac{yP’(y)}{P(y)}\to0,$ then $$\frac{yh’(y)}{h(y)}=\frac{\alpha P(y)+yP’(y)}{P(y)}\to\alpha.$$

On the other hand, if $yh’(y)/h(y)\to L,$ then let $Q(y)=h(y)/y^{L}.$ Then $$\frac{yh’(y)}{h(y)}=\frac{LQ(y)+yQ’(y)}{Q(y)}=L+\frac{yQ’(y)}{Q(y)}.$$

So the limit (1) being $L$ means $h(y)=y^LP(y),$ for some $P$ satisfying $yP’(y)/P(y)\to0.$ If $h’$ is also monic near zero, $b_{n+1}-b_n\to L.$

$$h’(y)=y^{L-1}(LP(y)+yP’(y))$$

$$h’’(y)=y^{L-2}\left(L(L-1)P(y)+(L-1)yP’(y)+yLP’(y)+yP’(y)+y^2yP’’(y)\right)\\=y^{L-2}P(y)\left(L(L-1)+(L+1)\frac{yP’(y)}{P(y)}+\frac{y^2P’’(y)}{P(y)}\right)$$

So, at least when $L\neq1,$ it is enough that $\frac{y^2P’’(y)}{P(y)}\to0.$ It is sufficient for that expression to be bounded away from $L(L-1).$

When $L=1,$ we need $2P’(y)\neq -yP’’(y)$ near $0.$ This amounts to $y^2P’(y)$ not having infinitely many zero derivatives near zero.

Comment: Apparently all the steps of the proof remain valid if $k<-1$. Do you have some reason to be uncertain?

Comment: Was just thinking it through, tryi g to see if I missed anything. @dfnu

Comment: So, it is possibile that $\frac{g'(z_n)a_n}{g(a_n)}\not \to L$, for $n\to \infty$, despite the hypothesis that $\frac{g'(x)x}{g(x)}\to L$ when $x\to \infty$. Correct?

Comment: @dfnu Yeah, I just haven’t worked out the right condition. Obviously, if $g’(z_n)/g’(a_n)\to 1,$ we get convergence to $L,$ but that is tricky to find conditions to ensure that.

Comment: Yes, very interesting! I am also working on that. I upvoted the question for now. I did not accept  it only because I wanted to "leave the field open" to further investigation. I do appreciate your solutions and prosals, though!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I came up with a much simpler and more stringent *sufficient* condition. Using your notation, $$a_{n+1} = a_n\left(1+\frac1{g(a_n)}\right),$$if $g(x)$ is positive and differentiable, $g(x) \to \infty$ for $x\to \infty$, and $\frac{g'(x)}{x^{\alpha-1}}\to L$ for some positive $\alpha$, then $$\frac{a_n^\alpha}{n}\to \frac{\alpha^2}L.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$m=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})a_{n}^\frac{1}{k}<\int_{a_{0}}^{a_{m}}x^{\frac{1}{k}}dx=\dfrac{k}{k+1}(a_{m}^{\frac{k+1}{k}}-a_{0}^{\frac{k+1}{k}}).$$Thus$$\dfrac{k+1}{k}m<a_{m}^{\frac{k+1}{k}}\Rightarrow\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{a_{m}^{k+1}}{m^{k}}\geq(\dfrac{k+1}{k})^{k}.$$Also $a_{m}^{-\frac{1}{k}}<(\dfrac{k+1}{k}m)^{-\frac{1}{k+1}},$implies that$$a_{n}=a_{0}+\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}a_{m}^{-\frac{1}{k}}<a_{0}+(\dfrac{k+1}{k})^{-\frac{1}{k+1}}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}m^{-\frac{1}{k+1}}.$$However$$\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}m^{-\frac{1}{k+1}}<\int_{0}^{n}x^{-\frac{1}{k+1}}dx=\dfrac{k+1}{k}n^{\frac{k}{k+1}}$$We obtain$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{a_{n}^{k+1}}{n^{k}}\leq(\dfrac{k+1}{k})^{k}.$$In conclusion,$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{a_{n}^{k+1}}{n^{k}}=(\dfrac{k+1}{k})^{k}.$$